# default to join fetch for child entities in spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa and hibernate.

When I fetch an entity, multiple select statements are being issued to fetch the relationships.

Is there a way to instruct spring data jpa to always use joins when possible?

Ex. entities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date ts;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent") 
   private List<Child> child;
}
```

child:

```
@Entity
public class Child {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName="parentId")
   private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: Seems it's not possible... :-(

Comment: The Child field should be a collection?

Comment: @Argb32 yes, typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch type of the child relationship is specified to be Lazy. That instructs not to load the relationship with parent entity. Try Eager fetch type.

If you want the fetch type to be lazy you can decrease number of statements by using @BatchSize on Child (Children?) mapping.

**Upd:**

As the problem is when Child entity is fetched Entity graph should help. Declare it:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
name = "child.withParent",
attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("parent")
}
```

)

And use with a repository method:

```
@EntityGraph("child.withParent")
Child findWithParentById(Long id);
```

Comment: The problem is when I fetch the Child. There are 2 selects being issued. 1 for the child, 1 for the parent. Seems like that should be a join by default

Comment: Ok, another solution is needed then.
I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was aware of NamedEntityGraph, but was hoping I wouldn't have to defined NamedEntityGraph for each entity and that there was a default in spring data jpa, but it doesn't appear so.